# How to get these rows from many to many table, which contains 0 in exact column?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, having-clause

```
a|a_id|b_id
1| 13 | 0
2| 14 | 0
3| 13 | 57
4| 13 | 0
5| 15 | 11
6| 15 | 0
7| 15 | 234
8| 14 | 0
```

So I want to return only these `a_id` which all rows in `b_id` are 0. In this case it would be **a_id = 14**.

```
a|a_id|b_id
1| 13 | 0
2| 14 | 0
3| 13 | 57
4| 13 | 0
5| 15 | 0
6| 15 | 0
7| 15 | 0
8| 14 | 0
```

In second case **it would be 14 and 15**

What I tried:

```
select a_id
from id_table
group by a_id
having max(b_id) > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select a_id
from mytable
group by a_id
having max(b_id) = 0
```

This assumes no negative value in `b_id`. Otherwise you could do:

```
having max(b_id <> 0) = 0
```

Comment: Correct! Well can you explain `having max(b_id) = 0` this row, cuz I used > 0, but it wasn't correct.

Comment: @SahinUrkin: well, if the greatest value is `0` (and there are no negative or `null` values) it means that there are only 0s. Your expresssion was checking if *any* value was *greater* than 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full rows then you can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.a_id = t.a_id and t1.b_id <> 0);
```